# reading extended data from a sensor

Tags: sensor

I am using a [Sensor](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/418/MS5637-02BA03-768293.pdf) to measure barometric preassure. It states an extended range. What exactly is this ? And how can I read from this range ?

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this will be a range over which lower accuracy specifications apply, so good readings 300-1200, rough readings 10-300 and 1200-2000. Read as for the normal range. It says the ADC will be linear over that range, but it doesn't say what the pressure sensor will do!

Answer (score 1):

You should read the complete datasheet. Absolute accuracy data is only given for the operating pressure range of 300 to 1200 mbar. Relative accuracy data is given only for 700 to 1000 mbar. There is no accuracy data for the range of 10 to 300 mbar and 1200 to 2000 mbar.
But the air pressure on top of the Mount Everest is 325 mbar and down at the Dead Sea about 1065 mbar. The operating pressure range should be sufficient for an altimeter not used in passenger airplanes.

Comment: It is for an application which already has some pressure. We are purging an enclosure. What do you mean by relative accuracy ? So beyond 1200mbar how is the data mapped ?

Comment: @Board-Men please read the datasheet page 6 and following. Look for application notes for this sensor on the web side of the manufacturer. Beyond 1200 mbar you get only uncompensated pressure readings.